# facebook development in php from localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost

I want to develop facebook application using php in my localhost.

my project name is **facebook** But When I try to registration in faecbook developers for application with domain name **`http://localhost:80/facebook`** It show a error message.

The error message is **`App Domains: http://localhost:80/facebook should not contain protocol information`**

How can I solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don´t add a folder to the App Domain, it´s just "`localhost`" there, without protocol (http) or port.

Site URL should be: `http://localhost/facebook`

You don´t need to add port 80 (default HTTP port)

Works with and without sandbox mode btw (i just tried). You may just have to set a valid category in the "App Details" section too.

Comment: then you did not follow my directions. what exactly do you have in the input fields now? (app domain and site url)

Comment: btw, you have to set a valid category in the "app details" section too, but that´s another error and it shows exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @Shahadat, You cant get the same error message, tell the exact error

Comment: so what error do you get exactly? it must be a different one, IF you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're filling in the 'app domains' field, it should contain a domain which matches your 'website' or 'app on facebook' url - e.g. it should be 'something.com', without protocol identifier, and no path. Just the domain.

P.S: This won't work with localhost except for testing purposes in sandbox mode. (how would it work for any other user if the code is on your machine?)